# API for writing an addon for recording browser events

Tags: selenium, browser-addons

I'm aware of the *Selenium IDE* addon for *Firefox*. Looked at its source code too, but it is not becoming readily obvious to me what all API it is using to hook into the document and window events.

I'm trying to write, from scratch, a very basic "recorder" addon (like Selenium but sans all its GUI) that records mouse clicks and text input and writes them to a file on the local filesystem. I don't know what API(s) I should be looking at.

Though I'm developing for Firefox 38 on Linux initially, I'd love to be able to port as much code as possible for writing a similar addon for Chrome. So, a cross-platform addon API, if one exists (I doubt though!), would be ideal.

Comment: Don't use Selenium IDE.  Use 'Selenium Builder' instead and then re-ask your question.

Comment: +1 for suggesting Se Builder. However, its recording I'm finding worse than Se IDE. Is Se Builder supposedly better than Se IDE?

Comment: I don't know how it works. I would guess its just a Javascript api. Its possible that while the IDE is recording your Javascript console might reveal listener events?  If not, just email one of the Selenium Builder developers.  Builder was forked from IDE about 2 years ago and is more maintained by SauceLabs company.